# Find parameter so equation has solution

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

The equation $$\sin x + \cos 2x = m, \: \:m\in R$$ has solutions $\Leftrightarrow m \in  \: ?$

I know I should rewrite like $2\sin^2 x - \sin x + m - 1 = 0$.
The equation has solution $\Rightarrow$ discriminant $\ge 0$, but what other conditions do I have to impose ?

The answer is $[-2, \frac{9}{8}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite as :

$$2\sin^2 x - \sin x -1=-m$$

Now the minimum value of $2\sin^2 x - \sin x -1$ occurs at $\sin x=\frac14$ (Which is $= -\frac{9}{8}) $and maximum at $\sin x =-1$ (Which is $2$)

*[You can see this using simple quadratic equation concepts]*

Therefore : $ \dfrac{-9}{8}< 2\sin^2 x - \sin x -1 < 2$

For equation to have solution, $-m$ must lie in this range. Hence you get :

$-m \in \Big[-\dfrac{9}{8},2\Big]$

$\implies m \in \Big[-2,\dfrac{9}{8}\Big]$